# How Can I Align The Steps to Solve a Simple Algebraic Equation with MathJax?

Tags: mathjax

I am 14, and working on depicting the steps to solve a simple algebraic equation like this: 2x - 3 = 7 with MathJax.

However, I want to align the required steps as depicted below:

[image: Steps to solve two-step equation.]

My question, therefore is how could I do this with MathJax? I tried using the Amsmath package, but couldn't get anywhere.

I need this because I am building an Android app, and I lose image quality with pictures like this.

Thank you.

Comment: MathJax has a different syntax for coloring math. It uses `\color{<color>}{<math>}` which doesn't work in LaTeX, where `\textcolor` should be used. This implies, unfortunately, that the question is off topic here.

Comment: Well. We have a mathjax tag, which implies, I'd have thought, that the question is on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible code.

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
2x&-3&={}&7\\
&\color{red}{{}+3}&\color{red}{{}+{}}&\color{red}{3}\\
\color{blue}{\frac{\color{black}{2x}}{2}}&&={}&\color{blue}{\frac{\color{black}{10}}{2}}\\
x&&={}&\phantom{0}5
\end{alignat}
```